# How i can insert a value type date time in my table?

Tags: sql-server

The problem is in don't insert value in the table.

I check consult of SQL Server for insert values for the of type date time by not solved problem.

```
USE [NameTable]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]
    ([UserSID]
    ,[ApplicationSID]
    ,[Username]
    ,[Email]
    ,[Password]
    ,[PasswordQuestion]
    ,[PasswordAnswer]
    ,[IsApproved]
    ,[IsOnline]
    ,[IsLockedOut]
    ,[LastLockedOutDate]
    ,[FailedPasswordAttemptCount]
    ,[FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart]
    ,[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount]
    ,[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart]
    ,[Comment]
    ,[CreationDate]
    ,[LastActivityDate]
    ,[LastLoginDate]
    ,[LastPasswordChangedDate]
    ,[LastChangedUser]
    ,[LastChangedDate])
     VALUES
    ('db0a4054-5efe-4945-bd08-ba057cd7990f'
    ,'F830DCF0-7D82-4FC1-B258-0502D0F00029'
    ,'lvillarroel'
    ,'lvv_umss@gmail.com'
    ,'vcaMiL4tVmj4wyXhTw/ISz344maPUDzcV2z8SFVKMF0='
    ,'NULL'
    ,'NULL'
    ,1
    ,0
    ,0
    ,'2019-01-14T18:10:40'
    ,0
    ,'NULL'
    ,0
    ,'NULL'
    ,''
    ,'2019-01-14T18:10:40'
    ,'NULL'
    ,'NULL'
    ,'NULL'
    ,'db0a4054-5efe-4945-bd08-ba057cd7990f'
    ,'NULL')
GO
```

The result is a message

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result with code that you have tried & you got an error.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem is `'null'`, you don't need to include single quote around `null` values.

Or you can directly omit the columns which has no value (i.e. `'null'`).

Your code works perfect even the dates are in  `2019-01-14T18:10:40` SQL Server will implicit convert it to `date`/`date time` for you.

So, in your code you have a `[LastChangedDate]` & you supply `'NULL'` value which is incorrect & will not implicit convert to datetime. So, try it just `null` instead of `'null'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you will write `'NULL'` then SQL Server understand and consider it as a string value. So if you want not want to insert values of `Datetime` then you need to simply write `NULL` as shown below.

Here I have used same date value as you have used in your SQL query trying to run and as in your question.

```
Create table Users([LastLockedOutDate]  DateTime
    ,[CreationDate]  DateTime
    ,[LastActivityDate]  DateTime
    ,[LastLoginDate]  DateTime
    ,[LastPasswordChangedDate]  DateTime
    ,[LastChangedDate] DateTime)

Insert Into Users Values('2019-01-14T18:10:40', '2019-01-14T18:10:40', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

SELECT * FROM Users
```

You can find the demo here [**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/XVEMU80113)